# How to sum dynamic input field values with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

On my `view_cart.php` I have an overview of all the products to be ordered. Here I like to get the total quantity of products.
Every row represents a product where i have a field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_qty[0]" value="3" />
```

and for example

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_qty[1]" value="5" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_qty[2]" value="2" />
```

Now i like to get the total (here `10`) to specify some shipping. I tried

```
$("input[name='item_qty[]']").each(function() { 
    test_qty += $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define and set counter `test_qty` to `0`, use selector *name starting with `[name^='item_qty']`* and parse `value` attribute to integer with `parseInt` (*for example*, you can also use multiplication, like `test_qty+=$(this).val()*1` or unary operator `+` like `test_qty+=+$(this).val()`).

```
var test_qty = 0
$("input[name^='item_qty']").each(function() { 
    test_qty +=parseInt($(this).val(), 10)  
})
console.log(test_qty)
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xzpvL380/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the element the wrong way, please, try this one:

```
$("input[name^='item_qty']").each(function() { 
                test_qty +=$(this).val();
                console.log(test_qty);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `class="item"` to each `input` and then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var test_qty = 0;
  $(".item").each(function(){
    test_qty += parseInt($(this).val());
    console.log(test_qty);
  });
});
```